# Event-driven programming with Java and SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, event-driven

Say, there is a legacy Service oriented application running on Java and supported by a SQL Server database.
Is there a way to monitor a table for new records (Inserts), without actually polling it every few min?
Since the app is legacy undergoing the effort of integrating with a newer event-based model like Kafka (or even Queuing) will be over-kill and shot down.

Comment: Consider using `SqlDependency` for SQL Server, I'm not sure if there is an equivalent class in Java but it's based around a Service Broker queue

Comment: Why would Kafka be shut down? Have you looked at using Debezium with sql server?

Comment: It is an old system with very few resources. Needed something quick and dirty to do the trick. Will check Debezium. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16) Queues support a blocking read statement WAITFOR...RECEIVE, which enables a client connection to run a query that returns  immediately after a message appears in a queue.

So you can put a trigger on a table that SENDs a message to a target Service Broker Service, and have one or more clients continuously monitoring the Service's Queue.